# ID needed for this socket

Tags: identification, components

I need to plug a couple of sensor cables into these sockets but the plugs supplied on the cables don't match the sockets and I have not been able to identify anything that looks close so far. I am no electronics expert and am probably not being accurate enough with my terminology to help narrow the search online enough. So any help from this forum would be great.

The sockets are about 9mm x 3mm, and contain these four prongs that the plugs need to accept which are not small and square or round like most seem to be but wide and in a vertical orientation. The lower two corners of the sockets have triangular-ish fills and there are two holes in the top face of the socket to accept locking bumps on the top of the plug – if I don't get an exact match to the type I can trim the corners of a squared-off plug if needed.

[mystery socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfMTb.jpg)
[image: mystery socket low]

Comment: Welcome! What's the pin to pin spacing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with them, but I'd suggest looking through catalogs from Molex, JST, and TE (three particularly big connector manufacturers who make this kind of thing). Wide contacts like this are usually called "blade contacts".

Comment: ... and blade contacts are generally designed to carry high current for a given amount of space, so if just browsing doesn't find anything, trying a search with "power", "current", "high power" or "high current" may narrow things down (or, it may not help at all).

Answer (score 1):

I love connector identification questions.

Those really look like Molex "Microblade" series connectors:

[image: source https://forum.digikey.com/t/molex-51004-something-else-compatible/24055]

- Crimp housing part number 51004-xxxx (https://docs.rs-online.com/804a/0900766b813c3e28.pdf, drawing http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/510040300_sd.pdf)
- Straight PCB header part number 53014-xxxx (https://docs.rs-online.com/7d4e/0900766b813c4418.pdf, drawing http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/530140310_sd.pdf)
- Right angle PCB header 53015-xxxx (datasheet https://docs.rs-online.com/9a41/0900766b813c4428.pdf, drawing http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/530150510_sd.pdf)

Now, the problem is that the entire series have been made obsolete. Molex doesn't do it anymore. But based on the part number, you may find some knockoffs on cheap china-based marketplaces.